# How to render attribute-property by condition in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue, how to render `to` property by condition?

for example I have this markup and by set `clickable=true` then this `div` will have `:to` property if not, will have regular div (no `:to`).

```
<div :to="path">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div :to="false && path">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
   <div v-if="clickable" :to="path">
      <img src="..." />
   </div>
   <div v-else>
      <img src="..." />
   </div>
```